# JavaScript - How to pass/store value from function to form hidden field?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Please, Im having an issue with the JavaScript below. I'm not very used to JavaScript... what I have below is a ticket booking script that displays the number of tickets selected, total amount and seat row / seat number. I want to pick the number of ticket, seat row, seat number ( for all the selected seat e,g 3,5 and 8,2 means row 3 seat 5 and row 8 seat 2) and amount  in the HTML form HIDDEN FIELD as shown somewhere in the code and then send these values to another page through the submit button and then get them by PHP.

```
<div class="booking-details">
  <ul class="book-left">
    <li>Time </li>
    <li>Tickets</li>
    <li>Total</li>
    <li>Seats :</li>
 </ul>
 <ul class="book-right">        
    <li>: April 3, 21:00</li>
    <li>: <span id="counter">0</span></li>
    <li>: <b><i>$</i><span id="total">0</span></b></li>
 </ul>
 <div class="clear"></div>
 <ul id="selected-seats" class="scrollbar scrollbar1"></ul>


 <!-- HTML FORM WHERE HIDDEN INPUT IS LOCATED TO GET THE VARIABLES -->
```

```
            <div id="legend"></div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var price = 52; //price
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var $cart = $('#selected-seats'), //Sitting Area
                $counter = $('#counter'), //Votes
                $total = $('#total'); //Total money

                var sc = $('#seat-map').seatCharts({
                    map: [  //Seating chart
                        'aaaaaaaaaa',
                        'aaaaaaaaaa',
                        '__________',
                        'aaaaaaaa__',
                        'aaaaaaaaaa',
                        'aaaaaaaaaa',
                        'aaaaaaaaaa',
                        'aaaaaaaaaa',
                        'aaaaaaaaaa',
                        '__aaaaaa__'
                    ],
                    naming : {
                        top : false,
                        getLabel : function (character, row, column) {
                            return column;
                        }
                    },
                    legend : { //Definition legend
                        node : $('#legend'),
                        items : [
                            [ 'a', 'available',   'Available' ],
                            [ 'a', 'unavailable', 'Sold'],
                            [ 'a', 'selected', 'Selected']
                        ]                   
                    },
                    click: function () { //Click event
                        if (this.status() == 'available') { //optional seat
                            $('<li>Row'+(this.settings.row+1)+' Seat'+this.settings.label+'</li>')
                                .attr('id', 'cart-item-'+this.settings.id)
                                .data('seatId', this.settings.id)
                                .appendTo($cart);

                            $counter.text(sc.find('selected').length+1);
                            $total.text(recalculateTotal(sc)+price);

                            return 'selected';
                        } else if (this.status() == 'selected') { //Checked
                                //Update Number
                                $counter.text(sc.find('selected').length-1);
                                //update totalnum
                                $total.text(recalculateTotal(sc)-price);

                                //Delete reservation
                                $('#cart-item-'+this.settings.id).remove();
                                //optional
                                return 'available';
                        } else if (this.status() == 'unavailable') { //sold
                            return 'unavailable';
                        } else {
                            return this.style();
                        }
                    }
                });
                //sold seat
                sc.get(['', '4_4','4_5','6_6','6_7','8_5','8_6','8_7','8_8', '10_1', '10_2']).status('unavailable');

            });
            //sum total money
            function recalculateTotal(sc) {
                var total = 0;
                sc.find('selected').each(function () {
                    total += price;
                });

                return total;
            }
        </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to pass a value to an hidden input you can set the value like this:

```
$("#price").val(total);
```